Reflective shadow maps sampling
I'm following the old RSM paper and I don't understand the sampling section. I understand that it's a disc pattern, that is more scattered away from the center and has some weights.
I don't understand how it relates to the RSM.

Should these samples be stored in a uniform?
If I'm computing the contribution for some pixel, and it's origin is at some (s,t) of the shadow map, do I need to ensure that all my samples pick up unique pixels of the RSM? Eg, the sample pattern should be relative to the texture size?
What do i do if the next pixel over projects to the same (s,t) but a different sub pixel location, should I do something to get a different sampling pattern than the previous pixel?
What happens at the edge of the RSM, if my samples fall outside of it, are these just black lights with 0 intensity?

